# ASP.NET add CNAME to DNS

Tags: asp.net, security, dns, wmi

I'm trying to add a CNAME record to MS DNS Server on windows 2k8 but I got "Generic Failure" where running this code in ASP.NET but works in desktop application:

```
        ManagementScope _session = null;

        _session = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\MicrosoftDNS");
        _session.Connect();


        ManagementClass zoneObj = new ManagementClass(_session, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_CNAMEType"),null);
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = zoneObj.GetMethodParameters("CreateInstanceFromPropertyData");

        inParams["DnsServerName"] = "xxx.com";
        inParams["ContainerName"] = "xxx.com";
        inParams["OwnerName"] = "test.xxx.com";
        inParams["PrimaryName"] = "en.xxx.com";


        zoneObj.InvokeMethod("CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation", inParams, null);
```

It seems that the problem returns to user permission, How can I grand **_IUSER or ASPNET to MicrosoftDNS or anything else to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to run the IIS Application as an administrator user. Here is an older page with information on doing this. http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount

You can change the account under 'Basic Settings' in you IIS 7.0+ site and clicking on 'Connect As'. Try running your code as an administrator user and see if it works.

You may also be able to impersonate the code as another user, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4